# XML serialization of list of class containing a System.Enum field causing crash

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums

I have a custom type with two enum members. I'm trying to create a list of this custom type, then serialize that list to XML. When I try and do this, Unity (I'm working in Unity) crashes, which it's never done on me before.

I've narrowed the issue down to this from my serialization code:

```
xmls.Serialize(stream, dataCollection);
```

So the issue poccurs when the XMLSerializer attempts to serialize my List. I have no idea why though! So any help would be appreciated.

Code below.

**XML Serialization code**

```
public static void WriteGenericCollectionToXML<T>(T dataCollection, string filePath) where T : IEnumerable, ICollection
    {
        //Check to see if file already exists
        if(!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //if not, create it
            File.Create(filePath);
        }

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using(Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append))
            {
                xmls.Serialize(stream, dataCollection);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Code to create list of objects of my custom type**

```
public  List<BlockType> t = new List<BlockType>();

        t.Add(new BlockType(true));
        t.Add(new BlockType(true));
        t.Add(new BlockType(true));

        SaveLoad.WriteGenericCollectionToXML(t, Application.dataPath + "/test.xml");
```

**Custom type**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public enum BaseBlockType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Animals")]Animals,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Geometry")]Geometry,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Letters")]Letters
}

public enum LetterBlockType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "A")]A,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "B")]B,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "C")]C,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "D")]Z,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "E")]X,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "F")]F,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "G")]G
}

public enum AnimalType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Elephant")]Elephant,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Giraffe")]Giraffe,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Tiger")]Tiger,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Sheep")]Sheep
}

public enum GeometaryType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Square")]Square,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Triangle")]Triangle,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Circle")]Circle,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Star")]Star
}

[XmlType]
public class BlockType
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public BaseBlockType baseType;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public System.Enum subType;

    public BlockType(BaseBlockType baseT, System.Enum subT)
    {
        //Set base type
        baseType = baseT;

        //Set sub type
        subType = subT;
        //possibly need to perform checks that sub-type is acceptable
    }

    public BlockType(BaseBlockType baseT)
    {
        //Set base type
        baseType = baseT;

        //Set sub type
        subType = RandSubType(baseType);
    }

    public BlockType(bool random)
    {
        if(random)
        {
            //Set base type
            int enumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(BaseBlockType)).Length;
            int rand = Random.Range(0, enumLength);
            baseType = (BaseBlockType)rand;

            //Set sub type
            subType = RandSubType(baseType);
        }   
    }

    public BlockType()
    {}

    public System.Enum RandSubType(BaseBlockType baseType)
    {
        int subEnumLength;
        int subRand;

        switch(baseType)
        {
        case BaseBlockType.Animals:
            subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalType)).Length;
            subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
            return (AnimalType)subRand;
        case BaseBlockType.Geometry:
            subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(GeometaryType)).Length;
            subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
            return(GeometaryType)subRand;
        case BaseBlockType.Letters:
            subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(LetterBlockType)).Length;
            subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
            return (LetterBlockType)subRand;
        default:
            Debug.Log("Block Sub Type Selection not working");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        string result = baseType.ToString() + "." + subType.ToString();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool Equals (object t)
    {
        var test = t as BlockType;

        if(t == null)
            return false;

        return(test.baseType == this.baseType && test.subType == this.subType);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        return this.GetHashCode ();
    }
}
```

Comment: the try/catch around serialization - what is the exception it writes? If no exception put a try/catch around the entry point of your code and see what it says

Comment: Just tried wrapping the problem line in a try catch, and it still crashed Unity!  Very annoying.

Comment: Try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,e)=>Console.WriteLine(e);

Comment: I bet it's choking on the `System.Enum subType;` since [`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is abstract.

Comment: I think you're right. I first tried flagging that member as {XmlIgnore], but that didn't work - still crashed, but I then removed that member from the class and it worked. Problem is, I need that member! Any thoughts about how I could get around the issue? I'm thinking I might have to reorganise the way I do my enums to avoid using System.Enum.

Comment: The .Net serializer chokes on `public System.Enum subType;` but has no problem once `subType` is marked as `[XmlIgnore]`.  (Of course, it's not serialized.)  If the Unity serializer chokes on ignored fields I'm not sure what to suggest; does it choke if you the ignored public field with an ignored public property?   If you can figure out how to make the Unity serializer not choke, I may be able to suggest a way to actually serialize the `System.Enum` value.

Comment: Also, consider using the support for polymorphism built in to `XmlSerializer`.  See [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer: Declaring Serialization Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) and [Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ca1ks327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You have a `StackOverflowException` in `GetHashCode()`.  You need to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems here:

- You have an infinite recursion in

  ```
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
      return this.GetHashCode(); // Fix Me
  }
  ```

  Apparently `XmlSerializer` uses the hash code for something, so you need to fix this, which should be easy.
- You are trying to directly serialize an object `System.Enum subType;` of type [`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Unfortunately, this type is abstract, so you can't serialize this directly.  You're going to need to add more information to your XML, namely the `enum` type being serialized.

I would suggest doing this by adding the following wrapper class to encapsulate the enum type:

```
public sealed class XmlEnumWrapper
{
    System.Enum value;
    Type type;

    [XmlAttribute("enumType")]
    public string XmlEnumType
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == null)
                return null;
            return Type.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                Type = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Type = Type.GetType(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class EnumWraperBase
    {
        public abstract System.Enum BaseValue { get; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Wrapper")]
    public sealed class InnerEnumWraper<T> : EnumWraperBase
    {
        public InnerEnumWraper() { }

        public InnerEnumWraper(T value) { this.Value = value; }

        public T Value { get; set; }

        public override Enum BaseValue { get { return (System.Enum)(object)Value; } }
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string XmlValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (Value == null)
                return null;
            var wrapper = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(InnerEnumWraper<>).MakeGenericType(Type), new object[] { Value });
            // Handle [XmlEnum(Name = "XXX")] attributes applied to enum values by making a nested call to XmlSerializer
            return (string)wrapper.SerializeToXElement().Element("Value");
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                Value = null;
            }
            else if (Type == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Type was not set");
            }
            else
            {
                var xelement = new XElement("Wrapper", new XElement("Value", value.Trim()));
                var wrapper = (EnumWraperBase)xelement.Deserialize(typeof(InnerEnumWraper<>).MakeGenericType(Type));
                Value = (wrapper == null ? null : wrapper.BaseValue);
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public System.Enum Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            if (value != null)
                type = value.GetType();
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (!value.IsEnum || value.IsAbstract)
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            this.type = value;
            if (this.value != null && this.type != this.value.GetType())
                this.value = null;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value == null ? "" : value.ToString();
    }
}

public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)result;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string GetXml(this object obj)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(this XContainer element, Type type)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            return new XmlSerializer(type).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(writer, obj);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }
}
```

Then, modify your class as follows, fixing the infinite recursion, ignoring the `subType` field, and serializing instead a `public XmlEnumWrapper XmlSubTypeWrapper` property as an *`Element`*:

```
[XmlType]
public class BlockType
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public BaseBlockType baseType;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public System.Enum subType;

    [XmlElement("subType")]
    public XmlEnumWrapper XmlSubTypeWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return (subType == null ? null : new XmlEnumWrapper { Value = subType });
        }
        set
        {
            subType = (value == null ? null : value.Value);
        }
    }

    public BlockType(BaseBlockType baseT, System.Enum subT)
    {
        //Set base type
        baseType = baseT;

        //Set sub type
        subType = subT;
        //possibly need to perform checks that sub-type is acceptable
    }

    public BlockType(BaseBlockType baseT)
    {
        //Set base type
        baseType = baseT;

        //Set sub type
        subType = RandSubType(baseType);
    }

    public BlockType(bool random)
    {
        if (random)
        {
            //Set base type
            int enumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(BaseBlockType)).Length;
            int rand = Random.Range(0, enumLength);
            baseType = (BaseBlockType)rand;

            //Set sub type
            subType = RandSubType(baseType);
        }
    }

    public BlockType()
    { }

    public System.Enum RandSubType(BaseBlockType baseType)
    {
        int subEnumLength;
        int subRand;

        switch (baseType)
        {
            case BaseBlockType.Animals:
                subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalType)).Length;
                subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
                return (AnimalType)subRand;
            case BaseBlockType.Geometry:
                subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(GeometaryType)).Length;
                subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
                return (GeometaryType)subRand;
            case BaseBlockType.Letters:
                subEnumLength = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(LetterBlockType)).Length;
                subRand = Random.Range(0, subEnumLength);
                return (LetterBlockType)subRand;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Block Sub Type Selection not working");
                return null;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = baseType.ToString() + "." + subType.ToString();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object t)
    {
        var test = t as BlockType;

        if (t == null)
            return false;

        return (test.baseType == this.baseType && test.subType == this.subType);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var code1 = baseType.GetHashCode();
        var code2 = subType == null ? 0 : subType.GetHashCode();
        return unchecked(~code1 ^ (7 + code2 << 3));
    }
}
```

Having done so, your XML will now look like:

> ```
> <ArrayOfBlockType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>     <BlockType baseType="Letters">
>         <subType enumType="LetterBlockType, euj3revx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">LetterBlockTypeC</subType>
>     </BlockType>
>     <BlockType baseType="Geometry">
>         <subType enumType="GeometaryType, euj3revx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">Triangle</subType>
>     </BlockType>
>     <BlockType baseType="Animals">
>         <subType enumType="AnimalType, euj3revx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">Tiger</subType>
>     </BlockType>
> </ArrayOfBlockType>
> ```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBxrXW).

Comment: Thanks for that. Can't believe I missed the GetHashCode(). I'm getting an error in the SerializeToXElement extension method at the element.Remove() line though::::                                                                                                                             **System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Parent is missing**

Comment: @MatthewSawrey - I don't get that error on .Net.  You can remove the `if (element != null) element.Remove();` logic, it's a small, optional reduction in memory usage.