# XML serializing Enum type properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums

I'm trying to XML serialize a class containing a enum property.  If the property is declared using a specific enum, it works just fine.  But I need the property to be of type Enum, so I can set it to different enum types.  However, when doing this I get an exception.

> The type [namespace].Simple may not be used in this context.

I've tried different attributes on the enum definition, but haven't gotten it right so far.  Is there a way to do this?

```
public enum Simple : byte
{
    one = 0x01,
    two = 0x02,
    three = 0x03
}

public class Foo
{
    public Enum Simple { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
        {
            try
            {
                var foo = new Foo
                {
                    Simple = Simple.three
                };
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enum` is abstract and cannot be serialized. A possible approach to solve is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981669/1132334).

The common primitive base type of `enum` is `int` (by default, can also be byte or long for instance).
So you could as well simply use this integer base type instead, like `byte Simple` in your `Foo` class.

In case you need the string representation to appear in xml (identical to the enum field name), expose it as `string Simple`.

Comment: The problem is that members in the different enums can have the same value, i.e. I need to know which enum type that has been serialized.  When using strings, would it be possible to get "[Enum].[Member]" in the XAML, and use this also when deserializing?

Comment: I don't think so. maybe someone else has a better idea, what I would do  in this case is to include two fields in the serialization: one the enum type name, and the other the corresponding byte/integer value. Then do part of the deserialization after the actual xml deserialization by like `Enum.Parse<type>(value)`. Applying @Asw's solution and including the type name as part of the attribute value could also work. But that does not save you from some custom deserialization effort either.

Comment: Intriguing idea.  Will investigate... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set EnumMember attrubute on your DataContract that you want to serialize, for more specific info visit 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on [dlatikay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132334/dlatikay)'s idea about splitting the enum into two strings for enum type and member name, I've come up with the following solution.  The example converts to from a `Foo` object to XML string, and back to a new `Foo` object again.

```
public enum SimpleEnum : byte
{
    one = 0x01,
    two = 0x02,
    three = 0x03
}

public class Foo
{
    private Enum _simple;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Enum Simple
    {
        get { return _simple; }
        set {
            _simple = value;
            var type = Simple.GetType();
            var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type);
            EnumType = Simple.GetType().FullName;
            EnumMember = Simple.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string _enumType;
    public string EnumType
    {
        get { return _enumType; }
        set { _enumType = value; }
    }

    private string _enumMember;
    public string EnumMember
    {
        get { return _enumMember; }
        set {
            _enumMember = value;
            _simple = (Enum)Enum.Parse(Type.GetType(EnumType), EnumMember);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(str))
        {
            try
            {
                var foo = new Foo
                {
                    Simple = SimpleEnum.three
                };
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
                Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(str.ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
                var foo = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```